# How to edit the code where I don't have the specifics ID's? In vbscript

Tags: web, vbscript

I have this code to enter in a website and login with vbs:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")   
 IE.Visible = 1   
 IE.navigate "http://www.mcmconsultores.com.br/arearestrita/Account/Login"   
 Do While (IE.Busy)   
     WScript.Sleep 10   
 Loop   
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("TXTEmailLogin")   
 Helem.Value = "blabla@something.com.br" ' change this to yours   
 Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("password")   
 Helem.Value = "ladkask" ' change this to yours   
 Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(2)   
 Helem.Submit
```

So, in the website I don't have the ID for password or eventually click on submit, how can I make this work?

Comment: You could search through the DOM looking for an `input` Element with a type of `password`.

Comment: You could limit your search by using `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` to return an array of your `input` Elements that you can then loop through checking for `Type` equal to `password`.

Comment: But in this case, the website has like, 3 formas, so, if I put by input, it gets the wrong form